# resultado doble en una lista de listas en haskell

Tags: haskell

hasta ahora he tratado de hacer que la lista ingresada se multiplique pero me sale error, se esta volviendo un dolor de cabeza.

```
doble:: [[Integer]]->[[Integer]]
doble [] = []
doble (x:xs)= if ((length x)>1) then map(\x->x*2) (x) :(doble xs)
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, es muy importante mencionar que error ocurre al publicar tu pregunta, revisa [ask], saludos.

Comment: En haskell, no puede haber un `if..then` sin el `else`. Tu código no está completo, por lo que seguro que te dará un error de sintáxis. Completa el código y comprueba la prioridad de los operadores, colocando paréntesis donde haga falta.